# Printing ASCII-like chars and there is a bug I can't find in char's drawing

Tags: c++, ascii

The following code prints the big letter with shadows (with `:` chars). If a user provides only 1 letter as input, everything is fine. But if the user inputs more than 1 letter, something goes wrong. The letters look strange (shadow is incorrect too).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A~Z and some symbols
int main()
{
    int A[6][6]={{0,1,1,1,1,0},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,1,0,0,1,1},
                 {1,1,0,0,1,1},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,1,0,0,1,1}};

    int B[6][6]={{1,1,1,1,1,0},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,1,0,0,1,1},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                 {1,1,0,0,1,1},
                 {1,1,1,1,1,0}};

    //int C[6][6]...........

    int k;

    string input;
    cin >> input; // a user inputs the symbols

    k = input.length()*8; // total length for define sum
    cout << k << endl;    // debug output
    int sum[k][8];        // the final array prepare to print

    // make all the space 0. Didn't sure if it's necessary.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            sum[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // start combining the symbols
    for (int h = 0; h < k/8; h++) // run input.length() time.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // 6 for vertical
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) // 6 for horizontal
            {
                //string word = input.substr(h,1);
                //I haven't program the other letters
                //so I print A temporary.
                sum[i+1][(h*8)+j+1] = A[i][j];
                if(sum[i+1][h*8+j+1])cout << i+1 << h*8+j+1 << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // casting the shadow
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (sum[i][j] == 1 && sum[i+1][j-1] == 0)
            {
                sum[i+1][j-1] = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    // top border
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) cout << "==";
    cout << endl;

    // start printing the sum.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // 8 for vertical
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) // k for horizontal
        {
            switch (sum[i][j])
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << "  "; // nothing there
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cout << "[]"; // part of a letter
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "::"; // the shadow
                    break;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n"; // for next line.
    }

    // bottom border
    for (int i = 0; i < k * 2; i++) cout << "=";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I enter 2 letters and it outputs
the first letter shifts 1 block down.

```
===============================
                    [][][][]
    [][][][]      ::[][][][]
  ::[][][][]      [][][][][][]
  [][][][][][]  ::[][]::::[][]
::[][]::::[][]  ::[][]  ::[][]
::[][]  ::[][]  ::[][][][][][]
::[][][][][][]  ::[][]::::[][]
::[][]::::[][]  ::::    ::::
================================
```

I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: You can try using a debugger.

Comment: You need to be clearer when posting. The title explains very little of the problem you want to solve. A way I like to think when posting a question is: how other people with the same problem can benefit from this question?

[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and refactor your question. Hope it helped! :)

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `int sum[k][8]`  to `int sum[8][k]`

Here is your output

```
AA
16
12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25 26
31 32 35 36
41 42 45 46
51 52 53 54 55 56
61 62 65 66

110 111 112 113
29 210 211 212 213 214
39 310 313 314
49 410 413 414
59 510 511 512 513 514
69 610 613 614

================================

    [][][][]        [][][][]
  [][][][][][]    [][][][][][]
::[][]::::[][]  ::[][]::::[][]
::[][]  ::[][]  ::[][]  ::[][]
::[][][][][][]  ::[][][][][][]
::[][]::::[][]  ::[][]::::[][]
::::    ::::    ::::    ::::
================================
```